# I'm not sure I like the "sticky score" feature

Tags: feature-request, undo

This is a new feature on SO: if you scroll down a page, the score and vote arrows next to every post become sticky: they stick to the top of the window rather than scrolling up with the top of the post.
Example of the old situation:

[image]

where the position of the score indicates that the post has more lines to it, which are out of view, so I'd need to scroll back up a bit to see the beginning of the post.
The new situation on the other hand

[image]

looks as if the post does start here. I'm not comfortable with that. There is no more visual indication of "top of post".
And what does the sticky feature achieve? That we can now up- or downvote without seeing the post from the top. Is that an improvement?

No, my request would be to roll this back.

Comment: [For context.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35041/move-the-vote-button)

Comment: Thanks; I wasn't familiar with that question.